# Como termino sessão?

Tags: suporte

Como faço logout aqui no Stack Overlow?

Já procurei em vários sitios e não encontro qualquer botão que termine sessão. Alguem me poderia ajudar?

Comment: [Fazer logout no SOPT](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1500/91)